# Does Wolfram|Alpha support Knuth's up-arrow notation?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Inspired by [Hjan's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53533/34836) to [Don't settle for a billion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/53509/34836), I wanted to try calculating the value of [image: 6↑↑100] using WolframAlpha.

I've tried using [`6↑↑100`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%E2%86%91%E2%86%91100), [`6↑100`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%E2%86%91100), and [`6 arrow 100`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%20arrow%20100) to represent [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnuthUp-ArrowNotation.html), but all three return financial information about Arrow (ARW) on the New York Stock Exchange.

**Does WolframAlpha support Knuth's up-arrow notation? If so, how do I use it?**

Answer (score 1):

I would say not yet, according to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ackermann%284%2C+4%29, as the copyable plain text under "Alternative Forms": "Knuth's up-arrow" looks like this: "2 ↑^27 - 3", however copying that exact text verbatim causes wolfram alpha to not recognize the query, even though it was the one to generate it. Unfortunately, all the other forms from that result don't work as well. Perhaps this is intentional?

According to https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/405659, you can still use some mathematica code to calculate modular results, the example given for the last 6 digits of 2^^10 is as follows:

```
Nest[Mod[2^#, 10^6] &, 1, 10]
```